# How can I use an application layout in rails for all controllers except a few?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application layout in my rails app to give a default header/footer for my entire website.  I have 1 controller that I dont want this to apply to (a checkout page), and an entire namespace that needs to have a separate default template (the admin interface, which has 10-15 different controllers).  What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

Will set the default for the entire layout. To override for a specific model, just have

```
app/views/layouts/mymodel.html.erb
```

I believe that will work for namespaces also, so long as your layouts directory structure matches your models' directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout

Just create new layout file (ie: /app/views/layouts/new_layout.html.erb) and set it in the beginning of the controller:

```
layout 'new_layout'
```